# Prevent htaccess HTTPS forward from working on localhost

Tags: apache, .htaccess, ssl

I have the following code in the my `htaccess` to forward all URLs to their `HTTPS` counterpart.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.merkd\.com
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://merkd.com [L,NC,QSA]
```

How can I modify this code so that this does not break my `localhost` build of my site? I run it on a local Apache server at the URL `http://localhost` where I do not have a SSL certificate.

If possible, could you also update the code so that `www.merkd.com/somepage` will forward to `merkd.com/somepage` rather than just defaulting to `merkd.com`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} merkd\.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://merkd.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.merkd\.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://merkd.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R,L]
```

I change `%{HTTP_HOST}` with the domain name, to avoid redirect to https and after to www.

Answer (score 1):

An alternative way is to exclude localhost from the conditions.

example:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^localhost
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R,L]
```